# How to see VS 2019 YAML Template Output generation

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, yaml, visual-studio-2019

I have yaml template in VS 2019 with variables like below.

```js
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "kubernetes1.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "kubernetes1.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "kubernetes1.chart" . }}
    draft: {{ .Values.draft | default "draft-app" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
etc.....
```

Now I want to see the output of fully generated yaml by filling those variable values. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is `kubectl` flag `--dry-run`.

Here is a link to the documentation references for this [`kubectl create`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands).

If you use the `dry-run` flag this will take your `yaml` and create it without applying it to the cluster.

Also if you want to see the output of that `yaml` you should use `-o yaml`, which redirects the output to yaml format.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually got a JSON parse error during actual deployment and that's why wanted to see the yaml output with generated values. But I am getting the same error during dry-run as well. Used command is "kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml --dry-run -o yaml" and then the error getting is "error: error parsing deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 35: could not find expected ':' ". Is there a way to see the generated yaml values before parsing it to JSON? Because I used VS generated yaml and not sure where is the format issue here

Comment: Can you provide information where are your variables stored and how are you parsing them into the deployment.yaml? Can you make most simple deployment with only one variable to check if parsing parameters is working?